# Flutter Socket.io Client with https server domain

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I found some problem when trying to connect with https server domain. Sometimes it can connect and return socket id but sometimes it cannot connect (got timeout connection).
However, there is client server currently built with React Native `socket.io-client`, which using `transport = polling` method and it works fine (always can connect).

On flutter project I used package: `socket_io_client: ^1.0.1`

for server `socket.io": "2.2.0`

code on server

```
const express = require("express");
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const FormData = require("form-data");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const restler = require("restler");
const pkg = require("../package.json");
const aes256 = require("aes256");
const cors = require("cors");

module.exports = class Server {
  constructor(config) {
    this._config = config;
    this._app = express();
    this._server = require("http").Server(this._app);
    this._io = require("socket.io")(this._server);
  }
...
```

on flutter client

```
_socket = IO.io(url, <String, dynamic>{
        'transports': ['websocket'],
        'forceNew': true,
        'timestampRequests': true,
        'autoConnect': false,
        // 'reconnection': true,
      });
      _socket.connect();
      // Handle socket events
      _socket.onConnect((_) {
        Utilities.log('connect: ${_socket.id}');
      });
```

I tried to log and see the network call on Charles,

[When cannot connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJwS2.png)

[When can connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hV9o.png)

I see then when can connect the sever kind of response `40` message (I assume that it's a hand shake)

More info is that, if I'm connecting to localhost it can always connect, but it's connect via `http` scheme.

Sorry if I missed something but I'm so confused right now, not sure it's a problem with flutter lib, server, or networking.

Answer (score 0):

Does your server provider support long-running connections? Some cloud providers don't support them.

In RN works, because polling doesn't require established long connections.  That might be the case.

P.S. You can use polling transport in dart and it also should work.
But why then use socket.io, if it's not "websocket" eventually?

P.S.S. Also check NGINX (or whatever you use), maybe it throttles connections.

Comment: The server is built on socket.io and they strictly state that I cannot change that part. 

From documentation of socket_io_client (https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-client-dart#usage-flutter) 
'it only works with dart:io websocket, not with dart:html websocket or Ajax (XHR), so in this case you have to add setTransports(['websocket'])"

But will check with the cloud service again, thank you